# Merging Associative arrays, get the latest, and remove a duplicate id

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I want to **merge 2 associative array**. when the user press the save and next button,

it should store all the data for that specific country. **If the `country_id` already exists, it should replace all of its value with the latest update of the user.**

```
window.main_array = []; // all of the data of sub_array will be transferred here.


// when a user clicks a button

// fetch all the input
sub_array = {
   'country_id':country_id, // <- should be unique

   'countryorigin':countryorigin,            // <- should be updated
   'marketingbudget':marketingbudget,        // <- should be updated
   'distributor':distributor,                // <- should be updated
   'salesrep':salesrep,                      // <- should be updated
   'commission':commission,                  // <- should be updated
   'retainer':retainer,                      // <- should be updated
   'expense':expense,                        // <- should be updated
   'buy_sell':buy_sell,                      // <- should be updated
   'instore':instore,                        // <- should be updated
   'merchandiser':merchandiser,              // <- should be updated
   'can_sell':can_sell                       // <- should be updated
};

// the main_array should have a unique country_id, and get the replace the old one with the latest if user updates a value for that country

 if(main_array.length <= 0){
    // just concat the two arrays if there are no data yet in the main_array
    main_array = main_array.concat(sub_array); 
 }else{
    // ???
    // should only get the latest input for the selected country'
    // replace the old data with the new one
 }

 // end of click event
```

Comment: I'm a little bit confused, maybe i'm not getting the question. Based on your code `sub_array` is an object and `main_array` is an empty array which I thought it will contain something? Do you have an example of how the main array would look like?

Comment: Because the main_array is just a container. all of the data of the sub_array will be transferred there.

Comment: By default main_array shouldn't have any values because it is just a container. after the user filled up the form, all of the user inputs will be stored to sub_array, then I will concat it to the main_array

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have "associative arrays". It has arrays, and it has objects. You are mixing up the two. In your code, `sub_array` is not an array at all, it is an object. I would suggest deleting the screenshot from your question, since it doesn't help clarify anything. Instead, list the actual output data you expect the code to produce, and whether it should be an object or an array - and please read up on the difference between those in JavaScript.

Comment: @MichaelGeary OOh sorry about that. I almost mixed up PHP with javascript. thank you sir. I'll research more about that subject.

Comment: No apology needed! It's an easy thing to mix up when you switch back and forth between languages like PHP and JavaScript that have features that are *similar* but not quite the same. Good luck and happy hacking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See code:

**Note:** It is written with assumption that you have already ran the form for awhile and `main_array` has already got some inputs for comparing.

```
var main_array = [
  {
    'country_id':"country_0", // <- should be unique

    'countryorigin':"Singapore",            // <- should be updated
    'marketingbudget':1000,        // <- should be updated
    'distributor':"lll",                // <- should be updated
    'salesrep':"tan",                      // <- should be updated
    'commission':"900",                  // <- should be updated
    'retainer':"_helloworld__",                      // <- should be updated
    'expense':99,                        // <- should be updated
    'buy_sell':true,                      // <- should be updated
    'instore':false,                        // <- should be updated
    'merchandiser':"hehe",              // <- should be updated
    'can_sell':false                       // <- should be updated
  },
  {
    'country_id':"country_1", // <- should be unique

    'countryorigin':"australia",            // <- should be updated
    'marketingbudget':1000,        // <- should be updated
    'distributor':"ddd",                // <- should be updated
    'salesrep':"smith",                      // <- should be updated
    'commission':"200",                  // <- should be updated
    'retainer':"_helloworld__",                      // <- should be updated
    'expense':50,                        // <- should be updated
    'buy_sell':true,                      // <- should be updated
    'instore':false,                        // <- should be updated
    'merchandiser':"hehe",              // <- should be updated
    'can_sell':false                       // <- should be updated
  },
  {
    'country_id':"country_2", // <- should be unique

    'countryorigin':"Malaysia",            // <- should be updated
    'marketingbudget':600,        // <- should be updated
    'distributor':"ooo",                // <- should be updated
    'salesrep':"robot",                      // <- should be updated
    'commission':"9005",                  // <- should be updated
    'retainer':"_ddddd__",                      // <- should be updated
    'expense':990,                        // <- should be updated
    'buy_sell':false,                      // <- should be updated
    'instore':true,                        // <- should be updated
    'merchandiser':"hehe",              // <- should be updated
    'can_sell':false                       // <- should be updated
  },
]; // all of the data of sub_array will be transferred here.


// when a user clicks a button

// fetch all the input
var sub_array = {
  'country_id':"country_1", // <- should be unique

  'countryorigin':"australia",            // <- should be updated
  'marketingbudget':5000,        // <- should be updated
  'distributor':"xyz",                // <- should be updated
  'salesrep':"john",                      // <- should be updated
  'commission':"100",                  // <- should be updated
  'retainer':"myer",                      // <- should be updated
  'expense':50,                        // <- should be updated
  'buy_sell':true,                      // <- should be updated
  'instore':true,                        // <- should be updated
  'merchandiser':"haha",              // <- should be updated
  'can_sell':false                       // <- should be updated
};

// the main_array should have a unique country_id, and get the replace the old one with the latest if user updates a value for that country

if(main_array.length <= 0){
  // just concat the two arrays if there are no data yet in the main_array
  main_array = main_array.concat(sub_array);
}else{
  main_array = main_array.map(function(country) {
    if (country.country_id === sub_array.country_id) {
      return sub_array;
    }
    return country;
  })
}
```

You might want to pay particular attention to the `else {}` clause because that is where the algorithm for solving your problem is.

What the `map` API does here is, it goes through every single object defined within the `main_array` list. Then for each iteration an object is returned.

See `Map` API documentation **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**.

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in this array.

So for solving your problem I would take the comparer object `country.country_id` and do a string match to see if it is the same as the `sub_array.country_id`, if it is the same then return `sub_array` (overriding) otherwise just return the original `country` object.